# PHP assign a $string in to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an action like this:

```
updatecreditbyaction('updatecredit', $_GET['uid'], array('extcredits2' => '+'.$paycredit));
```

The `updatecredit` is action name.

The `$_GET['uid']` is a user UID number.

The `array('extcredits2' => '+'.$paycredit)` is add the `$paycredit` amount to `extcredits2`.

My question is, I would like to use `$extown` to replace the `extcredits2`

I try the below coding,

```
$extown = "extcredits99";
updatecreditbyaction('updatecredit', $_GET['uid'], array($extown => '+'.$paycredit));
```

but when `$extown` inside the action, it was a blank value, not `extcredits99` how to resolve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$extown = array();
$extown['extcredits99'] = '+'.$paycredit;
updatecreditbyaction('updatecredit', $_GET['uid'], $extown);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the `extcredits99` store at database, and I use `$querySetting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_tradewar_setting");
while($rowSetting = mysql fetch array($querySetting)) {
         $excredits = $rowSetting['excredits'];
};`

the `$excredits` is extcredits99, how do I replace `$excredits` into `$extown['???']`

Thanks

Comment: just don't use quotation mark.. like this

$querySetting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_tradewar_setting"); 
while($rowSetting = mysql fetch array($querySetting)) {
 $excredits = $rowSetting['excredits'];
$extown = array();
$extown[$excredits] = '+'.$paycredit;
updatecreditbyaction('updatecredit', $_GET['uid'], $extown);
 };